# What applications did Laplace have in mind when he said (in 1812) that probability had become "the most important object of human knowledge"?

Tags: probability, math-history

> "It is remarkable that a science which began with the consideration of
>   games of chance should have become the most important object of human
>   knowledge." -- Laplace, Théorie Analytique des Probabilitiés, 1812.

What new applications of probability was Laplace referring to here, in 1812, when he declared that probability had become the most important object of human knowledge? What was probability used for at that time?

Comment: “In 1812 Pierre de Laplace (1749-1827) introduced a host of new ideas and mathematical techniques in his book, Théorie Analytique des Probabilités. Before Laplace, probability theory was solely concerned with developing a mathematical analysis of games of chance. Laplace applied probabilistic ideas to many scientific and practical problems. The theory of errors, actuarial mathematics, and statistical mechanics are examples of some of the important applications of probability theory developed in the l9th century.”  http://homepages.wmich.edu/~mackey/Teaching/145/probHist.html